# Using "decodeUri" is missing some characters (like '+')

Tags: apache-flex

I'm trying to get strings from a remote server using Flex (as) and i get the strings with "+" character (instead of spaces).

I am using the "decodeUri" and "decodeUriComponent", am i missing something?

Comment: huh?? Could you please make your question more clear?

Answer (score 2):

The `+` character is not replaced by `decodeUri`, but it is replaced by `decodeUriComponent`.
You can also try using escape/unescape methods.

Here the full info about what gets and what does not get replaced:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/package.html#decodeURIComponent%28%29